# Exposing only the getters of a singleton interface in C++

Tags: design-patterns, c++, interfaces, inheritance

I've got a file in my `includes` folder, which is the folder I expose, that isn't used externally and isn't supposed to be used too. When I noticed that and tried to remove it - I noticed that it's included in another file in the `includes` folder - the interface. So, removing this file won't solve anything because it'll break the isolation. My interface includes it only for some `set` methods that I use internally (I KNOW).

I'd like to separate all the setters so that way I'll be able to remove the unnecessary file and don't expose my `setters` but I'm not sure how to do it.

The issue is that the interface is a singleton since the data it holds should be consistent around the application. I'm not allowed to change that.

I'm the one creating the instance. Is there any way in which I can separate the `setters`, keep using both the `setters` and `getters` internally and only the `getters` externally?

I was thinking about an `interface_internal` that will inherit from `interface` and will be the one that  holds the `setters` but I'm not sure how to  proceed.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the structure you are dealing with when the question contains such abstract ideas. Can you [edit] your question to include some example code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: What won't splitting the interface into a "reader" and "writer" interface not solve your problem? If some code only needs the getters, they should be using the "reader" version of the interface.

Comment: I'm using the term "interface" in the way C# uses it -- an abstract class that only contains abstract methods.

Comment: Does it really have to be a singleton? C++ isn't that friendly for DI frameworks, but even doing injection by hand is often less trouble than singletons. And injecting an abstract base class as interface object should be easy.

Comment: @ojs: +1 for your comment, because, for instance, DI by hand avoids questions like this. Singletons make initialization easier, but restructuring the application becomes more difficult. DI makes refactoring easier, and refactoring can be a bigger time-suck then properly designing an object's lifetime and scope.

Comment: Of course, the OP was likely handed this mess to clean up.

Comment: @GregBurghardt this looks like a course assignment from 90s to me. Which means that mess must be completed exactly like the lecturer thought it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the setters private or protected obviously. Does that work?

Alternative is to have a base class with only getters that you expose to the public and a subclass in its separate source file, with all the setters declared. There’s the question whether you need the setters at all then, especially trivial ones.

Comment: regarding the private/protected - I don't really understand how it solves the issue. I won't be able to set from outside the class (but inside my module).

I was thinking about your alternative solution. In that case, am I creating an instance of the subclass in my module and exposing the base? I can't understand how it will work with a single inctance.

Comment: You have a function returning the singleton instance. It’s a baseclass function and declared as returning a baseclass pointer, but in reality it returns an instance of the subclass.